# How to implement c++ list's operator=?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is for an assignment over implementing c++ list so if anyone's going to ask "why don't you just use [very convenient thing] instead of list", the answer is ask my professor, not me. I also can't change my header. Note that this version of list only has to be able to take in int data types. Assume I hypothetically have every other function of list implemented already.

First, I've tried this, which went nowhere realizing I can't iterate through l which is constant (so no l.curr = l.curr->next etc).

```
Linkedlist& Linkedlist::operator=(const Linkedlist& l)
{
    if (this != &l)
    {
        this->clear();
        l.curr = l.head;
        for (int i = 0; i < l.numElem; i++)
        {
            this->push_back(l.curr->data);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I've also tried this, but once again I can't modify l in any way shape or form since it's constant. Type qualifier incompatible.

```
Linkedlist& Linkedlist::operator=(const Linkedlist& l)
{
    if (this != &l)
    {
        this->clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < l.numElem; i++)
        {
            this->push_back(l.front());
            l.pop_front();
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Sorry/let me know if I need to provide more info.

Comment: First one looks good but you're only handling the data not the links

Comment: You need to iterate through the list by other means, not with `l.curr = l.curr->next`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yeah I figured, which is why I tried the second thing, but again I can't modify anything to do with l. I just don't see how it's possible to iterate without modifying it.

Comment: @solarflare since this is only for int data types my push_back takes an int as a parameter, and does the work in creating a new link with that int as its data. Hence this->push_back(curr->data) where curr->data is an int.

Comment: `l.curr` is not the only variable out there. You can declare your own and modify it as you wish.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I tried this as well, but if I were to asign l to a new const Linkedlist, I end up back at square one not being able to iterate through it because I can't modify it because it's constant. Am I just too inexperience to know what you mean? /:

Regardless, R Sahu's solution works. I have no idea how though because I don't even know what auto is, so right now I'm going to look into it. Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 1):

> I can't iterate through `l` which is constant (so no `l.curr = l.curr->next` etc).

That's not how you would iterate over the nodes of the object. You can use:

```
for (auto iter = l.head; iter != nullptr; iter = iter->next )
{
}
```

In your case, you can use:

```
Linkedlist& Linkedlist::operator=(const Linkedlist& l)
{
    if (this != &l)
    {
        this->clear();
        for (auto iter = l.head; iter != nullptr; iter = iter->next )
        {
            this->push_back(iter->data);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't understand what auto does so I'll look into that now so I actually get what this is doing :D

Comment: @Nathan, You can probably use `Node* iter = l.head;` I didn't want assume the type. Using `auto` lets the compiler deduce the type.